# Automotive 20:1 Oscilloscope Passive Attenuator Design

Tags: power-electronics, automotive, test-equipment

I'm currently working on designing a switched, passive 20:1 attenuator for use in an automotive educational environment on PicoScope PC based oscilloscopes. In automotive electrical diagnostics, it's common to measure the control side of injectors or ignition coils (primary side) to view the voltage waveform. Due to the large voltage spike at that terminal as the coil is disconnected from the supply or gnd, it's common to use an attenuator before the oscilloscope input to reduce the signal magnitude to a safe range for the oscilloscope.

For my design, I chose a 20:1 passive attenuator which can be enabled or disabled by a switch (similar to a standard scope probe). The attenuation is set by a resistive divider with compensation capacitor. Note: the PicoScope input impedance is 1M || 24pF. Additionally, as this device will be used in an educational environment, I decided to add a 1.5kW bi-directional TVS diode (Vishay TransZorb series) to clamp any unintentional voltage spikes in the 1X mode to below the maximum input voltage of the scope (±100V).

Here is my current schematic:

Note: V_IN_1 is the BNC which the test leads connect to and V_OUT_1+, V_OUT_1- go to the PicoScope input.
[image: attenuator circuit]

My issue is that I'm having trouble selecting an appropriate switch for enabling or disabling the attenuator. The maximum voltage across the switch (worst case) may be around 250-300V. Most of the through hole toggle and slide switches that I can find are rated at around 120-250VAC (much less at DC I assume). Is having a switch for this a bad idea? I've thought about just having two input BNC jacks (1X, 20X) that the user will switch between. Though, I'm worried that students may damage the BNCs will repeated connecting/disconnecting. Are there any other options I should look into?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 250V AC is about 350V peak so should be compatible with your 300V pulsed waveform.

Comment: The DC rating is lower on switches because of the difficulty of breaking a DC arc. It shouldn't be an issue in your application.

Comment: Why 62pF - that seems too large. What is the cable capacitance?